# How to group linq expression only by date in datetime field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hello I need to run the following
query and group datetime field only by the date value.

```
 var startDateTime = regDate.Date;
            var endDateTime = regDate.AddSeconds(fullDayinSeconds);
            var res = from u in ObjectContext.Member.Where(o => o.RegisterTime >= startDateTime && o.RegisterTime <= endDateTime)
                      group u by new { u.PartnerId, u.RegisterTime.Date, u.partners.Name } into pgroup
                      let count = pgroup.Count()
                      select new PartnersUsersInfo 
                      { 
                         PartnerId = pgroup.Key.PartnerId.GetValueOrDefault(0),
                         PartnerName = pgroup.Key.Name, PartnerUsersAmount = count 
                      };
```

`u.RegisterTime.Date` - returns the exception *The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.*
I have tried to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` but it is not accepteble for group operations.

how to solve it ?

Comment: you can try add temp col with date and group by it

Comment: yes you are right, put you comment like an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try add temp col with date and group by it

Answer (score 0):

use
db.CallLogs.Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DateTime) == callDateTime.Date).ToList();